# Task/Submit doesn't get invoked

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I tried using the task module sample provided by microsoft at this [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp), and tried to publish the same codebase to my bot and tried submitting custom form but soon after clicking "sign up" nothing happens.

I understand that Task/Submit is being invoked using Microsoft Teams JavaScript SDK but SubmitTask() function doesn't send the value back to the bot.

[image]

I tried referring latest JavaScript versions of the Microsoft teams minified .js file, but still nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see from your screenshot what the 2nd parameter is properly, but any way try remove it, I think that will fix your issue.

Comment: I tried removing but that didn't help. I am passing MicrosoftAppId as second parameter.

Comment: so you're only passing 1 parameter now, or an empty string or similar in the 2nd param?

Comment: I am passing Microsoft App ID in second parameter and In the first parameter passing an object that contains some data which I need to handle at bot end, but nothing happens.

Comment: and if you remove the 2nd parameter entirely? e.g. :...submitTask (customerInfo);

Comment: sending one parameter without any appID worked. Thanks a lot - @Hilton

Comment: great stuff, glad to help! I've only ever gotten it to work this way, so don't ask me what that appId is SUPPOSED to do... ;-)